# How to allow users to view/edit their article(s) only - Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, permissions

I want to get the following article setup to work on one of my Joomla 3 sites:
- Users of the **user group A** can create, view and edit **only their own** artile(s)
- Users of the **user group B** can create, view and edit **their own article(s) as well as the articles from the **user group A**

I found a solution suitable for Joomla 2.5, but I can't seem to get it to work on my Joomla 3 site:
[Allow Users to View ONLY articles they Author](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=673&p=3469670#p3469670)
- the reply from "rcarey"

I checked Joomla 3's [ACL tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Controlling_What_Users_Can_See) as well, but couldn't find anything usefull for my issue.

Is there any way how to solve this please?

Thanks for any ideas/hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way doing so without coding.

But if you know a little bit about how Joomla works, or just google for it you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/alex7r/overrideany) to create **override** of specific Joomla core method without modifying the core itself.

What you want to do here is override articles `getListQuery()` to something like:

```
class ContentModelArticles extends ContentModelArticlesBase
{
    protected function getListQuery(){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = parent::getListQuery();

        /*
         * $group that can see all the posts
         */
        $group = 10;
        if(!in_array($group,JFactory::getUser()->getAuthorisedGroups())){
            $query->where($db->qn('created_by').' = '.$db->q(JFactory::getUser()->id));
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

That will do it.

Comment: Hi Alexandr, thanks for your quick reply - much appreciated. The implementation of a custom plugin is something I haven't really done before. I played with (hacked..:) ) some of the core .php files before, did some overrides as well. And that's why I rather like to use an override (using your [plugin](https://github.com/alex7r/overrideany) ) than to modify the core files. My PHP knowledge is really on a noob level, so here's my noob question: Should I replace the `public function onAfterRoute()` with the `protected function getListQuery()` in your plugin's code? Thanks again for any advice

Comment: No, I've updated example at https://github.com/alex7r/overrideany/blob/master/README.md#example But in a few words: you should change `initial` and `target` file. And place proper class definition (see example) and your function `protected function getListQuery()` to the `target` file. If you still face issues, you can create an issue at github, it will be more handy to solve `coding` problems there. )

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go and will reach out to you on github if needed. And post my finding here afterwards, of course - for the fellow struggling DEVs...:)

Comment: Hello Alexandr, I added a new issue on  [your plugin's Github page](https://github.com/alex7r/overrideany/issues) - fyi.

Comment: Just updated the issue and provided code of solution

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Alexandr - your plugin together with your sugggested solution (code) solved my issue. **Hint for all Joomla beginner-devs**: the above code belongs into your **target** file which you specify inside the `overrideany.php`. And the **initial** file in this case will be `/components/com_content/models/articles.php`. Everything else is described [here](https://github.com/alex7r/overrideany/issues/1).